# Definition of ${\cal{O}}_X$-modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We can define an $R$-module (alternatively to the usual definition) to be an abelian group $M$ together with a ring morphism $\varphi_M: R \to \text{End}(M)$ (sending $x$ to the multiplication-with-$x$ map).

Now let $(X, {\cal{O}}_X)$ be a ringed space. I want to define the notion of ${\cal O}_X$-module. I started by the following "natural" approach:

> An ${\cal O}_X$-module ${\cal F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$ with ring morphisms $\varphi_{{\cal F}(U)} : {\cal O}_X(U) \to \text{End}({\cal F}(U))$ such that [we need to define module compatibility now] for $U \subseteq V$ the following diagram
> $$
> \require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> {\cal O}_X(V) @>\varphi_{{\cal F}(V)}>> \text{End}({\cal F}(V)) \\
> @V\text{res}VV @VV\Psi V \\
> {\cal O}_X(U) @>\varphi_{{\cal F}(U)}>> \text{End}({\cal F}(U))
> \end{CD}
> $$
> commutes, where $\Psi$ is induced by the restriction on ${\cal F}$ ... ???!? [realizes that this doesn't work].

As far as I can see there is no induced map $\Psi$, which is why this definition doesn't work.

I find this weird since my definition of module is pretty categorical and so I thought a categorical definition of ${\cal O}_X$-module is easily done. So my questions are:

1. Did I overlook something or can my definition be fixed somehow?
2. Rather philosophical: Why doesn't this work?

Comment: First class construct the sheaf of Homs, which to each open set U attaches the abelian group hom(F|U, G|U) not of morphisms from sections over u to sections over u but of morphisms between restrictions of the sheaves to U.

Comment: In other words, what you want to use is not the "external" $\operatorname{End}(\mathcal{F}(U))$ but the *internal* $\mathscr{End}(\mathcal{F})$.  If you want to study the notion further: the existence of an internal $\mathscr{Hom}$ is part of the definition of $\mathbf{Ab}(X)$ being a *monoidal closed category*.  (The "monoidal" part of this would be: to take the tensor product of two sheaves of abelian groups, first take the pointwise tensor product which forms a presheaf of abelian groups, then take the sheafification.)

Comment: Okay so if I understand you both correctly this would be the correct definition:
An ${\cal O}_X$-module ${\cal F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups together with a morphism of sheafs of rings $\varphi_{\cal F}: {\cal O}_X \to {\cal End}({\cal F})$.

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}$